# Are there any artificial intelligence projects in PHP out there?

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence

I'm interested in this field,but I'm only familiar with PHP so far.

If not,can you recommend a tiny but not so bad project that's easy enough to learn?

Comment: I don't believe there are any successful AI projects -- period. Much less PHP.

Comment: Define "successful".  And define "AI".

Comment: Man, pick up another language ... like Python. Peter Norvig at Google does Python. http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html

Comment: I don't think there are many PHP projects with any intelligence out there /flame ;-)

Comment: Why on earth would anyone write an AI project in *PHP*?

Comment: check this : https://github.com/php-ai

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I wondered the same when I realized 95% of code for AI is python related.
Why on earth should someone choose python for performance critical stuff ? It's among the slowest languages out there (and painful to code, subjective).

Comment: [a very approachable new php ai library](https://github.com/torian257x/ai-php-rubix-wrap) or pure rubix ml

Comment: oh boy, it's 2022 and these comments here have aged like milk ;)

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at Program O: https://program-o.com/

This is the description of the project:

> Program O is an AIML engine written in PHP with MySQL. Here you can
> find support, help, bot add-ons, a brilliant and friendly community, and of course the Program O download files.

And this mini tutorial for creating Neural Networks in PHP:
http://www.developer.com/lang/php/creating-neural-networks-in-php.html

This site could be interesting for you as well:
http://ai-php.com/

I notice many people dislike the idea of working with AI with PHP, but since most of the websites are in PHP, it will be a very interesting start to bring AI to them.

Comment: PHP is a very nice scraping language, I prefer it over pyhton a lot.
If the AI core is done in C (like libfann, sadly sorta deprecated) it is very fast as well.

Answer (score 6):

PHP Artificial intelligence links.
This is a github project and the project is beautifully active. download and use. But documentation is not complete

[php-ai/php-ml](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml)

[PHP-ML - Machine Learning library for PHP](http://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

There are two projects based on the ALICE project. They are Program E which isn't really developed any longer, and Program O which is. You can find them both on SourceForge

- Program O https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O
- Program E https://sourceforge.net/projects/programe/

Update: Program O is now on GitHub and is still developed. Program E is still orphaned and still located at sourceforge.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is mostly a web-based technology as far as I know.

AI work is typically done in other languages (e.g., Lisp).  But that doesn't mean you can't port the ideas to something else like PHP.

But Google found [this](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/PHP_AI.htm) - first hit on "PHP artificial intelligence".

Answer (score 1):

There are some other samples like spam detection (bayesian networks) or OCR (using newral networks). And i'm sorry guys, php is used also in a server side scripting language and also can be converted into desktop GUI applications with PHP-GTK.

Check this php samples: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/class/103.html

Comment: it can be used but it doesn't mean it is a *good idea*

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If it's not a good idea, let us know why. This comment is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching in this topic, but I'm looking for some kind of simple implementation of rule=based programming in PHP and I just found this http://www.swindle.net/php-rules/ in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Php probably won't be the best technology for AI but there's a library for neural networks which I used to implement on a website. http://ann.thwien.de/index.php/Main_Page It's quite simple but maybe it will help you.

Comment: Why would the AI favorite "python" be better technology ?:)
Python is much slower than PHP7, any fast AI code has to be written in C/C++ anyway.
The reason for python is probably like the reason why java was so popular: unversities