# How feasible is PHP as a Web Based Artificial Intelligence Language?

Tags: php, web, artificial-intelligence, server-side

So I'm sure you all know about Cleverbot, it's obviously a web application, however, my question is, what server side languages are capable for creating such a complex application? Would it be too much for, say, PHP?

Edit: By "too much" I mean will PHP slow down the server running it considerably compared to another language. The server would be something typical perhaps 256MB of ram and a dual core processor.

Comment: Most Web languages can be extended in a lower level (c, c++) language. C#, java and python all have decent ml libs available. I'm sure there are php extensions available as well.

Comment: You can hand off complex tasks like this from PHP to a queue where a worker written in another language does the CPU-intensive stuff. But, if you wanted to write it all in PHP, it would work - how fast/slow it would be is a how-long-is-a-piece-of-string question. It depends on too many things to give a sensible answer.

Comment: [Examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303357/are-there-any-artificial-intelligence-projects-in-php-out-there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82036/what-is-a-good-programming-language-for-ai - There is no "best" - it depends on what you want todo, a stupid web bot, why not php it would be okayish but not perfect. As soon as it becomes complex, i would not recommend php anymore.

Performance wise we canot predict how you code will look like, what data you want to crunch etc etc. Just keep in mind php is and never was made for long running processes.

Comment: Wow why the hate/downvote people? :)